# Quotes within quotes and a function

Tags: javascript

Due to a way the system is set up I need to do this as an onclick:

```
var name = "o'hanrahan";

var htmlData = '<ul class="">';
htmlData += '<li onclick="alert('hello ' + name)">Enter</li>';
htmlData += '</ul>';

return htmlData;
```

I have simplified the example. Name will change and could be anything.

How can I make quotes within quotes work in js?

Comment: That was a very poor series of three questions you asked there. Because you stubbornly refused to explain yourself the first two times you just wasted everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ' with a \ and also the rendered string for the name has to be inside of the single quotes.

```
htmlData += '<li onclick="alert('hello ' + name)">Enter</li>';
```

needs to be

```
htmlData += '<li onclick="alert(\'hello ' + name.replace(/'/g,"\\'") + '\')">Enter</li>';
```

Now if the name has a `"` in it, you will have more issues.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3m4c/)

If the name has a `"` in it, you would need to replace `"` with `&quot;`

Comment: Should be `name.replace(/'|\\/g,"\\$1")`

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape them:

```
var name = "o\\'hanrahan";

var htmlData = '<ul class="">';
htmlData += '<li onclick="alert(\'hello ' + name + '\')">Enter</li>';
htmlData += '</ul>';

return htmlData;
```

And as you're inserting a string with the same quote, that has to be escaped twice

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bu3Rw/1/)

A better way of doing this would be

```
var name = "o'hanrahan";

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(name);
}, false);
li.innerHTML = 'Enter'

ul.appendChild(li)

return ul;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bu3Rw/4/)

That way the name doesn't matter

Comment: How would I put the backslash in name, if name varies.